# Http Referer header changed after first load

Tags: django, http, request, request-headers

So I have a django application and it's acting weirdly as for the first call the http_referer is correct but from the next call even for the static files the referer is changed to the current domain.

Comment: The `http_referer` for the image is meant to be the URL that includes that image. The browser doesn't remember the original referrer and use that for all requests on the site.